# Clarify 'almost surely different' and an example that has random variables with same distribution but almost surely different

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $X$ be a normally distributed variable with $N(0,2)$

Define $Y(\omega) := -X(\omega)$ for all $\omega \in \Omega$

1. What does almost surely different mean? I understood that, for example $P(X = -Y)=1$ is almost surely (implied from surely). My initial assumption of almost surely different is that something is different everywhere but except for that one particular case
2. One similar question (I couldn't comment) have the below answer to prove almost surely different. I have some difficulties in understanding it particularly why $P\{\omega : X(\omega)=0,Y(\omega)=0\} \leq P\{\omega : X(\omega)=0\}$ ?

My understanding is because for the particular $\omega$ that makes $X(\omega)=0$, it also makes $Y(\omega) = 0$, so $P\{\omega : X(\omega)=0,Y(\omega)=0\} = P\{\omega : X(\omega)=0\}?$

The Answer:$$P\{\omega : X(\omega)=Y(\omega)\} = P\{\omega : X(\omega)=0,Y(\omega)=0\} \leq P\{\omega : X(\omega)=0\} = 0$$

Comment: 1) Almost surely different means that $P(X = Y) = 0$. 2) $P(A)\leq P(B)$ if $A\subset B$.

Comment: $\Pr(A\cap B)\le \Pr(A)$

Comment: @Stratossupportsthestrike I see it now, thanks!

Comment: @Andrew I see it now, thanks!

Comment: More generally, "almost surely" just means "with probability $1$". If someone says "$X-Y$ is almost surely rational" it means "$P(X-Y \text{ is rational})=1$", i.e. $P(\{\omega:X(\omega)-Y(\omega)\text{ is rational}\})=1$. If someone says "dig($X$) is almost surely blue-magic directional", then it means $P(\text{dig}(X) \text{ is blue-magic directional})=1$, i.e. $P(\{\omega:\text{dig}(X(\omega)) \text{ is blue-magic directional}\})=1$. A very common one is that "$X_n\to c$ almost surely as $n\to\infty$" means $P(X_n\to c \text{ as }n\to\infty)=1$.

Comment: @JamesMartin Thank you so much! it's very clear to me now!